# Is there an efficient algorithm for finding the distance between multiple 2d points without repeating a calculation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, distance

I am trying to create a Python function which will take x coordinates and y coordinates as an input and calculate the distances between all of the data points.  The distances should be stored as a list (or array) and passed back to the calling program.  The algorithm I am starting with looks like the example below.

```
def distance(x, y):
    dist = []
    for j in range(len(x)):
        for i in range(len(y)):
            """
            Don't calculate the distance between the same point
            since it will obviously be zero
            """
            if j != i:
                mag = (x[j] - x[i]) ** 2.0 + (y[j] - y[i]) ** 2.0
                dist.append(np.sqrt(mag))
    return dist

x_vals = [2.3, 3.6, 1.8]
y_vals = [1.6, 4.8, 2.8]

vals = distance(x_vals, y_vals)
print(vals)
```

This algorithm will calculate the distance between points 1-2, 1-3, 2-1, 2-3, 3-1, and 3-2, returning the following lists

```
[3.4539832078341086, 1.2999999999999996, 3.4539832078341086, 2.6907248094147422, 1.2999999999999996, 2.6907248094147422]
```

While the results are correct, the algorithm repeats measurements.  As you can see the distance from point 1-2 is the same as 2-1, and the distances between 1-3 is the same as 3-1, as well as 2-3 is the same as 3-2.  In other words, I would like to create a more efficient algorithm that only calculates between 1-2, 1-3, and 2-3.  While this sample only contains 3 data points (i.e. 3 pairs of x and y coordinates), I would like this algorithm to be applicable to a much larger number of datapoints, and be as efficient as possible since this could be applied to a large number of data points.

Comment: You are likely looking for caching.

Comment: what about using a structure like a dictionary to remember distances already computed?

Comment: Or [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)

Comment: Making your inner loop for i in range(j+1, len(y)): avoids the problem of computing both 1-2 & 2-1,and  2-3 & 3-2, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be faster since it does not use explicit for loops

```
from itertools import combinations
from math import sqrt

def dist(x_vals, y_vals):
  " Distance of pair combinations of x_vals & y_vals "

  # Distance between zipped pairs
  dist2 = lambda z: sqrt((z[0][0] - z[1][0]) ** 2.0 + (z[0][1]- z[1][1]) ** 2.)

  # Use combinations to create desired distance pairs (i.e. 1-2, 1-3, 2-3, etc.)
  return list(map(dist2, combinations(zip(x_vals, y_vals), 2)))
```

## Test

```
x_vals = [2.3, 3.6, 1.8]
y_vals = [1.6, 4.8, 2.8]
print(dist(x_vals, y_vals))
# >> [3.4539832078341086, 1.2999999999999996, 2.69072480941474227422]
```

## Performance Testing

***Small Data Test***

Comparing posted solutions--list comprehension (6502 posting) and current posting (darrlg) based upon map & combinations are the fastest on small datasets.

```
Original Data (Small): 
 x_vals = [2.3, 3.6, 1.8]
 y_vals = [1.6, 4.8, 2.8]
```

1. Jon Original posting: **22.5 µs** ± 853 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of
   7 runs, 10000 loops each)
2. Jon Updated posting: **19.5 µs** ± 700 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
3. MTRW posting (scipy unique answers) **18.8 µs** ± 929 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
4. 6502 posting (based upon list comprehension) **5.85 µs** ± 239 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
5. Current solution: **5.74 µs** ± 195 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

***Larger Data Test (vector length 1000)***

Result: Scipy is much faster for larger datasets

```
Data
N = 1000
x_vals = [random.randrange(N) for _ in range(N)]
y_vals = [random.randrange(N) for _ in range(N)]
```

6. Jon Original Code: **3.2 s** ± 20 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev.
   of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
7. Jon Updated Code: **1.77 s** ± 39.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
8. MTRW posting (scipy unique answers) **7.65 ms** ± 80.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
9. 6502 posting (based upon list comprehension) **910 ms** ± 16.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
10. Current solution: **687 ms** ± 7.92 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Comment: Fantastic demonstration of the value of benchmarking. I would have expected pdist to be fastest by a ways.

Comment: Though I wonder if pdist, or numpy/scipy based answers in general, will perform better as the arrays get longer.

Comment: @mtrw--about to post an update that verifies your suspicions.

Comment: @mtrw--as you suspected, your numpy/scipy code is much faster with larger datasets.

Comment: This is an exemplary answer

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use a comprehension with two loops

```
dist = [((x_vals[i] - x_vals[j])**2 + (y_vals[i] - y_vals[j])**2)**0.5
        for i in range(len(x_vals))
        for j in range(i+1, len(x_vals))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use `scipy`? If so, the `scipy.spatial.distance` module has a function that calculates a variety of distance metrics and is smart about not calculating the redundant pairs: [scipy.spatial.distance.pdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html). This returns the unique set of distances. You can optionally use the helper function [squareform](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html) to get the redundancies if that makes your subsequent processing easier. For your given data:

```
import scipy.spatial

scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(np.array([x_vals,y_vals]).T,metric='euclidean')
# returns the unique answers array([3.45398321, 1.3       , 2.69072481])
scipy.spatial.distance.squareform(_)
# returns array([[0.        , 3.45398321, 1.3       ],
#                [3.45398321, 0.        , 2.69072481],
#                [1.3       , 2.69072481, 0.        ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my question that works, but I am still not happy with it as it used a for loop which is slow and I do not know how to transform it into a list comprehension or something faster.  Nonetheless, for completeness I am posting the answer here.
import numpy as np
import itertools

```
 def distance(x, y):
    dist = []
    k = 0
    for q in range(len(x) - 1, 0, -1):
        mag = [np.sqrt((x[k] - x[k + i + 1]) ** 2.0 + (y[k] - y[k + i + 1]) ** 2.0) for i in range(q)]
        dist.append(mag)
        k += 1
    return np.array(list(itertools.chain(*dist)))

x_vals = [2.3, 3.6, 1.8]
y_vals = [1.6, 4.8, 2.8]

vals = distance(x_vals, y_vals)
print(vals)
```